# Substituting text nodes between tags in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked for the answer to my question but couldn't exactly find it. Here's the HTML I have and cannot alter:

```
<div class="metadata"> 
    <span class="meta"> 
        <span>    
        </span>     
    </span> 
    <a class="sourceTitle" href="#">Link to site</a> 
      11d

     &nbsp;//&nbsp; 
    <span class="action">preview</span> 
</div>
```

Basically I need to change the `11d` to something like `March 13th`. I figured out all of the algorithm behind it, but can't for the love of god find a way to replace it. I have a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7tPTu/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the text node, then replace the text:

```
var text = $(".metadata").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap("<span class='textNode'>");

var target = $("span.textNode:contains('11d')");
target.text(target.text().replace(/11d/, "March 13th"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eBwjT/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put "11d" into its own span and give it an id.
Then you can just do:

```
$("#yourSpanId").text(yourText);
```

That will update yourSpanId with yourText. (If you are hardcoding a string, you need to put quotes:

```
$("#yourSpanId").text("some text");
```

Comment: As explained above he cannot alter the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately cannot alter the HTML

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for pointing that out, I should have read more closely!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that without jQuery using the innerHTML or innerText properties.

```
document.querySelector(".sourceTitle").innerHTML = "March 13th";
```

Comment: No sir. Have another look at the markup. You're editing the link text.

Comment: oh yep I didn't notice! My mistake :) I would have done it differently  by creating a time tag (with a datetime attribute).